# Retrieve post variable into an another method in controller

Tags: joomla-3.5

I don't understand how to retrieve some post data into specific method in controller. After submiting the form, the script goes into batch_categories() method into the controller in this method i define some specifics post variable to try retrieve them into _save() :

```
public function batch_categories()
{
  $cid = $this->app->input->get('cid', '', 'array'); 
  if ( $task == 'copy' )
    {
        $categories = $this->getCategories($cid);

        foreach ($categories as $cat)
        {
            list($title, $alias) = $this->_generateNewTitle($cat->id, $cat->alias, $cat->name);

            $_POST['name']  = $title;
            $_POST['alias']  = $alias;
            $_POST['parent_id'] = intval($cat_parent);
            $_POST['catid'] = 0;      
            $this->_save();
        }

        $this->app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('BATCH_COPY_SUCCESS'));
    }
}
```

In the save _save below, in the post data there ins't name, alias, parent_id, catid. Before with JRequest it worked well, now with JInput it doesn't work :

```
protected function _save()
{
 $post       = $this->app->input->getArray();
}
```

I need to know how to retrieve in _save() method, the differents posts variables (name, alias, parent_id, catid) defined in the batch_categories() method.

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 1):

Set the values directly on the jinput instead of setting them on PHP globals.

```
$app->input->set('title', $title);
```

Why don't you pass the values directly to the _save() method instead of setting them in PHP globals (it is not recommended to access PHP globals directly)?

```
$args = new stdClass();
$args->title = $title;
$args->alias = $alias;
$args->parent = intval($cat_parent);
$args->catid = 0;
$this->_save($args);
```

Change signature of _save method to accept an argument.